# How long were the events of Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

At the beginning of episode three we see a Padme who says she is pregnant but not showing, and at the end of the movie we see her delivering Luke and Leia. In other questions it is mentioned that the twins aren't premature, so is it ever explained what the actual timeline of events are in Revenge of the Sith? It feels like it goes one event after another with no breaks.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123020/51379

Comment: @Adamant I understand that she doesn't have to gain much and show a lot of difference but from one scene you see nothing to her being really with child in a later scene.

Comment: My wife recently gave birth to a new child, and for most of the first two trimesters you couldn't tell by looking at her that she was pregnant.  Not with clothes on, anyway, even close-fitting stuff.  Then, shortly before the third trimester - BAM! - her belly grew really quickly in only a couple of weeks.  It continued to grow after that point, but the change was less obvious to the casual observer.